# Import python library on pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, pyspark

Pretty new to Python.

I would like to read in some XML files from S3 and query them. I am connected to AWS and have spun up some EC2 clusters but I am not sure how to import the libraries I need to 
get the data.

I think using the xmlutils library to convert from xml to json and then using the read.json in the sqlcontext library which i do have access to will work (see below)

```
 converter = xml2json("S3 logs", "output.sql", encoding="utf-8")
 converter.convert()

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

logs = sqlContext.read.json("output.sql")
logs.registerAsTable("logs")

query_results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from logs...")
```

EDIT

I am trying to use this block of code to get xmlutils installed in my virtual environment on Spark from the cloudera link. (already set SparkConf and SparkContext)

```
def import_my_special_package(x):
    import my.special.package
    return x

int_rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4])
int_rdd.map(lambda x: import_my_special_package(x))
int_rdd.collect()
```

I tried passing both xmlutils and 'xmlutils' in the function argument as x but it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is your base operating system on the EC2 instances?

Comment: Can't install OS X on EC2. What OS is on the EC2 instances, not on the machine that you're accessing them with? Is it the default AMI?

Comment: Yes it is the default AMI

Comment: Check the packages installed. See if you can tab-complete pip to pip-2.7 to install the package

Comment: See this as well - http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-prepare-your-apache-hadoop-cluster-for-pyspark-jobs/

Comment: I tried using some of the stuff in the cloudera blog, but don't fully understand what it is doing

Answer (score 0):

pip and virtualenv are installed by default for Python 2.7 on 2015.03 AMIs - https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2015.03-release-notes/.

The above site shows how to access pip on the new AMI images.

Comment: I have both python27-virtualenv.noarch and python27-pip.noarch listed as installed, but when i try  any of 1.sudo pip-2.7 install modulename, 2. sudo pip install modulename, or 3.virtualenv-2.7 myproject && cd myproject I only get the error "command pip/virtualenv-2.7 not found" I am running the 2015.09 AMI running python 2.7, Spark 1.51, and Spark is running python 2.7.10